# Expression Expected for Copying to clipboard

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vba

My first time being here.

I have a VB Project, and I want it to Auto Copy when the Link is changed. But I don't want it to copy at start. I tried making this, but I got the "Expression Expected" error.

Code:

```
If txtImgurLink.Text = "Imgur URL" Then

End If
    If Else Then
        Clipboard.SetText(txtImgurLink.Text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put an If followed by an Else, and that's not allowed on VB.

Try this instead:

```
If txtImgurLink.Text <> "Imgur URL" Then
    Clipboard.SetText(txtImgurLink.Text)
End If
```